# How to use project-level variables in a local GitLab runner?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

is that possible to use *my-gitlab.example* project-level variables in a local GitLab runner? Let's say I have a registered runner on my machine and the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
stages:
  - stage-1
test:
  script:
    - echo "$my_var"
  stage: stage-1
```

and `$my_var=Hello World` is configured in CI/CD project settings stored on *my-gitlab.example*. Now I'm running
`gitlab-runner exec shell test` and an outcome I'd like to achieve is:

```
$ echo $my_var
Hello World
Job succeeded
```

but instead I receive an empty string...

Comment: When you're running the gitlab-runner manually it doesn't pull any variables from your GitLab server. Try pushing your example pipeline definition up to GitLab to have the pipeline run and it should work regardless if you have your own runners or are using a Shared runner (if they're set up on your instance, or if you're using gitlab.com).

Comment: Thanks @AdamMarshall. I just thought it's kinda doable because it's a bit tedious when I need to set up all variables each time I do testing locally.